# How can i update $stateParams without reloading the ui-view? angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Get the context, angular, ui-router, nothing special, a root view built with 3 named ui-views.
so in `index.html` we have

```
<body>
  <div ui-view='left'>
  <div ui-view='center'>
  <div ui-view='right'>
</body>
```

my route looks like

```
$stateProvider
 .state('main', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
   'left': {templateUrl: 'foo.html'},
   'center': {templateUrl: 'bar.html'},
   'right': {templateUrl: 'xyz.html'}
  }
 })
 .state('main.b', {
  url: '/b',
  params: { foo: {value: 'bar'} }
  views: { 'right@': {templateUrl: '123.html'} } // I wish to update $stateParams in 'left@' view
 })
 .state('main.c', {
  url: '/c',
  params: ...
  views: { 'left@': ..., 'center@': ..., 'right@': .. }
 });
```

Is there a way in going to b state to update the $stateParams in the 'center' and 'left' view?? I can get it using a service but i need to add a `$watch`  to the variable I need and it looks a little bit hacky to me.

Going into c state I can actually get what I want, but the view is reloaded, and i wish to avoid this behaviour cause i have a canvas in the 'left' view.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that using "Dynamic params" is now a better solution:

> When dynamic is true, changes to the parameter value will not cause the state to be entered/exited. The resolves will not be re-fetched, nor will views be reloaded.

```
$stateProvider.state('search', {
   url: '/search?city&startDate&endDate',
   templateUrl: 'some/url/template.html',  
   params: {
      city: {
         value: 'Boston',
         dynamic: true
      }
   }
 }
```

and then:

```
$state.go('.', {city: 'London'});
```

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#dynamic
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2709

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, but the question is how do we now differentiate between route changes caused by $state.go from your example (dynamic params) and somebody just going back by using the browser back button?

Comment: Thanks so much @julien-malige, I found any answer "all without dynamic tip" and when they spoke of dynamic, they had no example... your answer is complete! thanks!

Answer (score 33):

You could use the following to go to a specific route without reloading the views:

```
$state.go('.', {parm1: 1}, {notify: false});
```

The last object literal represents the options which you can pass along to `go`. If you set `notify` to `false`, this will actually prevent the controllers from being reinitialized. The `.` at the beginning is the absolute state name or relative state path you wanna go to.

The important thing is the `notify` though.

Comment: This somehow still causes all components in the view to $init and then immediately $destroy, which may lead to some serious performance issues. You can see if you add a `console.log()` to `this.$onInit()` and `this.$onDestroy()` within your components.

Comment: Controller is still re-instantiated using this method, $onInit is called.

Comment: Dynamic params is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting @christopherthielen from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1758#issuecomment-205060258:

> using notify: false is almost never a good idea, and is now
>   deprecated. Use reloadOnSearch if you must.
>
> You can also try dynamic parameters in the 1.0 version (currently
>   1.0.0-alpha.3). In your state, configure a parameter as dynamic and implement the uiOnParamsChanged callback :
>
> ```
> .state('foo', {
>   url: '/:fooId',
>   params: { fooId: { dynamic: true } },
>   controller: function() {
>     this.uiOnParamsChanged = function(changedParams, $transition$) {
>       // do something with the changed params
>       // you can inspect $transition$ to see the what triggered the dynamic params change.
>     }
>   }
> });
> ```

For a demo, have a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/T2scUAq0ljnZhPqkIshB?p=preview

Comment: Something that caught me off guard is that if you have `views` defined in the stateProvider definition, define your `controller` property in the `views` definition and not outside.
Eg. in docs: https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#views

`views: {
  header: {
    controller: function() {
    this.uiOnParamsChanged = function(changedParams, $transition$) {
      ...
    }
  },
    templateUrl: "header.html"
  },
  body: {
    controller: "bodyCtrl",
    templateUrl: "body.html"
  },
  footer: "footerComponent"
}`

Comment: The same github (before ChrstopherThielen comment) thread [also discusses the hack/workaround of manually changing `$stateParams[key]=value` and calling `$location.search(key, value)`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1758#issuecomment-116914200)