# How to differentiate between browser back button and $state.go (dynamic params)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, back

I need to simply update the URL params in some cases (through code) and not trigger any events. But, I still need to trigger certain actions if the user goes back using the browser back button or if he changes the url params manually.

Prior to UI-Router v1.x, I used to use `{ notify: false }` in combination with the `$stateChangeSuccess` event for this kind of stuff. But now that the [dynamic params](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45054066/413785) are the way to go I can't figure out how to make this work any more.

I have defined all the params of the route as dynamic, and when I execute the `$state.go(".", params)`, the controller does not get refreshed. Which is expected. The `$transition.onSuccess` does however still fire which I find slightly odd and I don't expect this event to fire in this case.

When I move back with the back button, or if I change a param manually, the same thing happens. The controller doesn't get refreshed and the `$transition.onSuccess` fires.

My main problem is how do I know one event came from the user, and the other one came from the code? What am I missing here? I checked out the transition param of the onSuccess callback, but couldn't find anything on it that would help me. Is there a different event/hook I should use or is this simply not possible any more with the latest UI-Router?

Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found a way to find out where the transition came from. If somebody has a different/better solution, please post it, I don't find this the neatest solution ever but it works and considering I couldn't find a better one, I'll stick with it until someone shows me a better way.

```
 // The "to:" ensures the event doesn't trigger for other routes
 this.$transitions.onSuccess({ to: "your.route" }, (trans) => {
  let changedParams = trans._changedParams();
  if (trans._options.source === "url" &&                  // transition came from URL change
      changedParams && changedParams.length > 0) {        // at least one param changed
    // do something
  } 
});
```