# Update $state.params without reloading a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way of updating the $state.params in AngularJS without reloading a controller?

I am trying to switch views from kanban to list view based on $state.params so that whenever user goes back or refreshes the page, they are loaded the right view. I don't want to reload the whole controller while doing this.

I have tried various combinations of

```
$state.go('mystate', { kanbanView: true }, { reload: false, inherit: false, notify: false });
```

None of them give a desired effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484457/how-can-i-update-stateparams-without-reloading-the-ui-view-angular-ui-router/33484586 is this not helpful for your issue?

Comment: @GoodSamaritan No, as the controller is reinitialized.

Comment: @GoodSamaritan Need to correct myself, the dynamic param from one of the answers does actually work. It no longer reloads my controller.